# Why do I have to change the linux host name for postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix-mta, hostname

I am trying to install postfix on my debian server. This is kind of a "general purpose" machine.

The server is running an apache web server and a couple of applications in docker containers. I would like to add a postfix mail server. Every tutorial tells me to change my hostname to `mail.mydomain.com`, but as I understand the hostname applies to the entire System. This is not primarily a mailserver so I would prefer not to commit to a hostname for the mailserver only.

What is the purpose of naming my host `mail.mydomain.com?`? Apache works fine without naming the system `mydomain.com`.

Am I meant to have a separate machine for my mail server? Or should I try to put it in a docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually no need to change the hostname. You will add an FQDN so that services like postfix can use it.

let's say your `/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   myhostname localhost localhost.localdomain

::1         myhostname localhost localhost.localdomain
```

set the FQDN to make the hostname be an alias for it:

```
127.0.0.1   myhost.domain.com myhostname localhost localhost.localdomain

::1         myhost.domain.com myhostname localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Then you can verify by `hostname --fqdn`

`myhost.domain.com`

While `hostname` is same as before `myhostname`